# Swift UIView draw diagonal one side and round corner

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, rounded-corners

I am drawing some view with diagonal side

like this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

code:

```swift
    let layerWidth = layer.frame.width
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    let pointA = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 44)
    let pointB = CGPoint(x: 150, y: 0)
    let pointC = CGPoint(x: layerWidth, y: 0)
    let pointD = CGPoint(x: layerWidth, y:44)
    bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: pointA.x, y: pointA.y) )
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: pointB.x, y: pointB.y))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: pointC)
    bezierPath.addLine(to: pointD)
    bezierPath.close()
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
    layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

as you can see, everything is fine, but I want to make the corners rounded

like this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

How can I achieve this result?

ADD:
and after receiving the result, I want to set this form as a mask for another view, but there is a problem: the second view has a border and if I set my own form, I lose part of this border

Code:

```
layer.mask = shapeLayer
```

wrong result:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey im founded way - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60035279/676205

just write 4 point like:

```
        let grayPath = UIBezierPath()
        addArcs(
            to: grayPath,
            pointsAndRadii: [
                (point: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), radius: 2),
                (point: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width - 104, y: 0), radius: 10),
                (point: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width, y: self.bounds.height), radius: 2),
                (point: CGPoint(x: 104, y: self.bounds.height), radius: 6),
            ])
        grayPath.close()
```

next set mask:

```
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = grayPath.cgPath
layer.mask = shapeLayer
```

if you have more efficient way or better performance, write it )